# "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, leaflet, react-leaflet

I want to use react-leaflet in my react project but I don't understand how to make it work I always get an error when I try to compile my code:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-leaflet/src/index.js 5:7
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| export { LeafletConsumer, LeafletProvider, withLeaflet } from './context'
|
> export type {
|   LeafletContext,
|   LatLng,
```

I don't understand what I did wrong :( I tried the example from the git repo and it did work so I don't know what is the difference between my project and the git. I checked the installation guide and I made everything required.

Here is my `webpack.config.js`

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

const htmlWebpackPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
  template: "./src/index.html",
  filename: "./index.html"
});

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "style-loader"
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              modules: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
              localIdentName: "[name]_[local]_[hash:base64]",
              sourceMap: true,
              minimize: true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [htmlWebpackPlugin]
};
```

My `package.json` :

```
{
  "name": "simple_webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "author": "Drigtime",
  "license": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
    "webpack": "^4.2.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.13",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "leaflet": "^1.3.3",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-leaflet": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

And the actual code that doesn't work

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Map, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet/src";

const Index = () => {
  return (
    <Map>
      <TileLayer
        attribution="&amp;copy <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
    </Map>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Index />, document.getElementById("index"));
```

Comment: Can you make a little gist with all of your files? Also, have you tried using this example: https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/tree/master/example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your import should be:

```
import { Map, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
```

Simple fix!

Comment: Oh you right, I don't know why I didn't think about this ^^' thnaks you very much ;)

Comment: @WilliamVarlet my pleasure!